# How to control radio button states within a custom SimpleCursorAdapter via bindView / newView for a listfragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment, simplecursoradapter, radiobuttonlist

I have a listfragment that manages row(s) of 2 radio buttons per row, where only one button is allowed to be checked, but I've not been able to manage the radio button states properly.

I'm pretty familiar with listview's recycling of views. I've tried many different avenues to no success, I realize I have to keep the states of the radio buttons, list position and probably whether the button has been initialized yet separately, which I can to with an interface.  It's where and when to set the radio button states within the adapter that I've been wrestling with.  Anything I've tried has one condition or another interfering with the other.  Like setting the radio button from the database initially, but when there is a recycled view with no radio button to be check and I do a radiogroup.clearCheck() that seems to override when the user chooses a button.

The state of the radio buttons should be controlled by 2 sources;

Database source: 
1) Database column has a value I'd like to set for the radio button initially, which I'd like to show as checked (.setChecked(true)) when the user hasn't had any interaction with that row yet, besides scrolling/no clicks.  OR  the Database column is 0 and no radio button should be checked.

User Action:
2) The users selects one of the two buttons, this should override the value of the database column.

Following is the rough framework for the fragments and adapters that I have:

The listview row xml file    **stackoverflow_2_radiobuttons_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/background"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:divider="@color/gray"
android:dividerHeight="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_text_left_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_text_left_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radiogroup"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_text_top_margin"
            android:text="RadioButton 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rb_1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_text_top_margin"
            android:text="RadioBUtton 2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:checked="false"/>


    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The list fragment: **StackOverFlow.java**

```
public class StackOverFlow extends ListFragment implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
Activity activity;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    String[] columns = new String[] { Mydb.COL_RB_STATE };
    int[] viewfields = new int[] {  };

    adapter = new StackOverFlowAdapter(getActivity(),     R.layout.stackoverflow_2_radiobuttons_row.xml,
            null, columns, viewfields);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

}

Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection = new String[] { 
            Mydb.COL_RB_STATE };

    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            MYProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
    String[] argz = new String[] { "'text'" };
    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor cursor) {
    ((SimpleCursorAdapter) this.getListAdapter()).swapCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    ((SimpleCursorAdapter) this.getListAdapter()).swapCursor(null);
}
}
```

The custom list fragment adapter:   **StackOverFlowAdapter.java**

```
public class StackOverFlowAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private Context context;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;
private int pos = 0;

RadioGroup radiogroup;
int iRowID = -1;
String row_Id;

Activity TestActivity;


protected static class ViewHolder {

    protected TextView h_rb1;
    protected TextView h_rb2;
    protected TextView h_radiogroup;
    protected int h_position;

}

public StackOverFlowAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

ViewHolder holder;

public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stackoverflow_2_radiobuttons_row, parent, false);
    holder.h_rb1 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rb_1);
    holder.h_rb2 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rb_2);
    holder.h_radiogroup = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    holder.h_position = (pos);

    if (cursor != null) {
        bindView(view, context, cursor);
    }
    view.setTag(holder);

    return view;
}

public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    final RadioButton rb_1 = (RadioButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.rb_1);
    final RadioButton rb_2 = (RadioButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.rb_2);
    final RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);


    radiogroup
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                    if (checkedId == rb_1.getId()) {
                        rb_1.setChecked(true);
                    } else if (checkedId == rb_2.getId()) {
                        rb_2.setChecked(true);
                    }  

                }

            });


}

}
```

I've seen a lot of answers using getView, but I haven't been able to find a good example or theory using bindView  and newView in a custom SimpleCursorAdapter with radio button states.  I haven't been successful manipulating anything in newView, I've been working mostly in bindView. So at this point I'm not sure how to proceed.  Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Have a great day.

Comment: I'm looking into using viewbinder and bndview possibly accomplish setting the various states.

Comment: ViewBinder and/or bindView are the places to do such things.  Also found out that clearing the buttons triggers onCheckedChanged.  So, onCheckedChanged should consider -1 (buttons cleared) and act accordingly.  

I had the opportunity this even to talk with Mark Murphy on the subject, and his bottom line on this was that listview isn't the correct way of doing this.  Some kind of pager should be used.  I'll keep you updated and THANKS Mark.